# How do I list objects stored in a Google Cloud storage bucket using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

*Let me preface this by saying I am completely new.  I code in SQL and SAS.*

I need to list all objects stored in a Google Cloud storage bucket.  The web GUI is insufficient as I am trying to locate one file among more than 6K files.

I'm in Google Cloud Datalab and using Python 3.6.  What is the easiest way to simply create a list (preferably something I can kick out to a local csv) of these objects?

Thank you

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) the following code will list all the objects in a bucket.

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
```

In `blob.name` you have the name of each object, in the code we print it to standard output. As you are saying you would like to have this output to a text file you can do it by appending this variable.

The docs for Storage are pretty solid, and have links to the GitHub repos that contains all the client code.

There's also a commandline utility `gsutil` which makes this stuff pretty trivial in bash scripts and the like.